# Advanced Custom Fields select field : How to echo the label, not the value?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am using the wordpress [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/select/).

This question is about the [select field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/select/), and in the documentation only tells me how to output the value, not the label/name.

I can't see this functionally in the documentation and was wondering if anyone had any ideas?

For example, to create Select field content, you simple do this...

```
gb : English
fr : Français
it : Italiano
de : Deutsch
pt : Português
es : Español
nl : Nederlands
be : Belgian
dk : Dansk
fi : Suomi
no : Norske
cz : Český
pl : Polski
hu : Magyar
ch : Schweiz
at : Österreich
eu : International
```

Then to output this, you write this...

```
<?php the_field('language'); ?>
```

For example if I select Polski in my post editor, the PHP will echo this value...

```
pl
```

I'm wondering if its possible to echo the label, I also want to be able to echo Polski, as well as the value pl.

If anyone knows of any documentation on how to do this or if you could help with a solution that would be most awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is so simple, just set the *Return format* to *Both (Array)* in ACF settings for this field. And then, when calling this field in PHP you can do it like this: `$lang = get_field('language'); echo $lang['label'] . ' - this is label, ' . $lang['value'] . ' - and this is label.';`

Answer (score 18):

The get_field_object() function requires the field KEY not the field NAME. See docs: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field_object/

So it should looks something like this...

```
$field = get_field_object('field_53d27f5599979');
$value = get_field('field_myfield');
$label = $field['choices'][ $value ];
```

You can find the field key by clicking on "Screen Options" > "Show Field Key" and it should appear next to the field type. See attached animated gif-cast below.

[image: Show Field Key]

Answer (score 9):

Throwing the solution here for better reading.

```
$field = get_field_object('field_name');
$value = get_field('field_name');
$label = $field['choices'][ $value ];
```

The value in `$label` will be the label related to the value set in `$value`.

Comment: The documentation for ACF is wrong on this part. You need to use the `field key` for `get_field_object`.

Like so: `get_field_object( 'field_5682538b28a71' );`

To get your field key, when you're in the ACF edit screen, open `Screen Options` and enable field keys

Comment: @AndrewLazarus The key field is no longer required.  It works perfectly with the field label.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps someone else.

To echo the value of an ACF select field:

```
$a = get_field_object('field_1234567'); 
echo $a['value'];
```

(where `field_1234567` is the field key obtained by selecting 'Show Field Key' in the Screen Options)